# MySQL query will not work in website when using JOINS

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with 3 tables, occupations, subjects and occsubject.  The subjects table has a list of subjects you would study at school.  The occupations table has a list of various careers.  The occsubject is a linking table which has the occupation id in it and the subject id, to link the other 2 tables together.

I am trying to run a query on a website to display all the occupations that have a subject matter of science, which is id 3.

Every simple query I write works perfectly and displays the correct results, however, as soon as I add the word JOIN into the query, it will not return any results.  The query works fine in PHP MyAdmin as well, so I really dont know what the problem is.

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT occName, occDesc3 
        FROM occupations 
        INNER JOIN occsubject
        ON occupations.occID = occsubject.occID
        WHERE subject = 3";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(!empty($result)){
      
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
?>

<table>
<tr>
<td><?=$row['occName']; ?></td>
<td><?=$row['occDesc3']; ?></td>
</tr>   
</table>

<?php
}
} else {
    echo "The results are empty";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post the complete schema and some sample data so that we can see what you're doing (or not doing).

Comment: `WHERE subject = 3` - is that ambiguous? should it be `WHERE occupations.subject = 3` ? Do you just get empty results or a white screen? Any errors? `printf("Error message: %s\n", $mysqli->error);`